# Emacs orgmode table formula to calculate different per km tariffs for trips under 100 km ans over 100km

Tags: org-mode, org-table, conditionals

I am new to Emacs Lisp. I have this [price table](https://sympavan.ch/orgmode.txt) in Org mode. A small portion of it is shown here:

```org
*** Destinations en France
| Destination              | Distance Km | Temps de trajet | Prix       |
|--------------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------|
| Ambilly                  |          10 |           00:30 | 45.00 Chf  |
| Annecy                   |          50 |           00:46 | 115.00 Chf |
| Annemasse                |          12 |           00:36 | 45.00 Chf  |
| Avoriaz                  |          86 |           01:29 | 197.80 Chf |
| Bourg-en-Bresse          |         112 |           01:24 | 257.60 Chf |
| Chamonix                 |          87 |           01:11 | 200.10 Chf |
#+TBLFM: $4=$2*2.30 Chf;f2
```

The table formula calculates prices for trips from the distance in km. But I would like to apply a different tariff for shorter trips. How would you write a conditional formula like that?

Comment: Instead of linking to a document, include a short example formatted as code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if(condition, value1, value2)` as documented at [Formula syntax for Calc](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc)

```
#+TBLFM: $4=if($2<100,$2*1.2,$2*2.3) Chf;f2
#                         ^
#                         |
#                 Insert the second tariff here.
```

Comment: Hello choroba, sorry for the code. The solution is perfect, it looks so simple when you explain it. Thanks for the reference in orgmode manual.

Comment: "Thanks" on stackexchange = upvote / accept :-)